# Displaying button when hovering over div in TailwindCSS

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

At the moment I am having a bit of trouble using TailwindCSS to display a button when hovering over a div in Vue. Normally, I'd use CSS to do it but I want to do it using tailwind.

I referred to the documentation using [visibility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility/#app) but it didn't work as expected. Is visibility normally for screen related elements? or it can be used for buttons and other content as well?

Code

```
<div>
  <button class="text-white invisible hover:visible">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wilth tailwind 3, this works with small changes: add `group` class to the parent div. Change `hover` in button to `group-hover` and everything works.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Based on my research and recommendations I have been told to use opacity, but opacity does not really give a good UI/UX feel to it so I went with another route  of creating a private boolean object in vue such as

`private hover: boolean = false;`

**Note I found `@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` are still viable in Vue.**

then in my `.vue` file I would consider using boolean variables to trigger the target I would want to hide and display.That is

On the target button or element you'd like to hide and display when hovering

```
<div class="mt-2 mb-2"
`@mouseover = "hover = true"`
`@mouseleave = "hover = false"`
>Hello World
</div>
```

Note: I am using Vue in tandem with typescript to achieve such a thing.

Comment: This problem does not require JS at all, CSS is powerful enough

Answer (score 68):

Add this to your `tailwind.config.js` file

```css
variants: {
    extend: {
        display: ["group-hover"],
    },
},
```

And then add `group` to your parent div and `hidden` and `group-hover:block` to your child element that you want to appear on hover of the parent.

```
<div class="group">
  <button class="hidden group-hover:block">Child</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want child to be flex then you have to <button class="invisible group-hover:visible">Child</button>  and in tailwind.config.js  visibility: ["group-hover"]

Comment: Tailwind 3 adds [styling based on parent state with `group-{}` modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state) by default.

Comment: I have two divs, but when I implement your code it hovers both at the same time ;(

Answer (score 38):

Here's my solution:

```
<div class="group">
  <button class="text-white hidden group-hover:block">Hello</button>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm using the `group` class, which applies a rule to the children instead of itself.

So when I write `group-hover:block` I'm saying: *"Apply the `block` class to this element if there's an `:hover` event dispatched on my immediate parent with the class `group`".*

[More information here.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover)

Comment: Did you have to do anything special with your tailwind files to accomplish this?  I am currently just using the tailwind / tailwind ui cdn and this does not work straight out of the box.  The group-hover works with some classes such as text color, but not the block class.  Hoping I don't have to compile using npm while just testing stuff. Thanks.

Comment: With tailwind 3 the group class is added by default, no need to modify the tailwind.config.js file

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24):

You cannot hover over a hidden element.

One solution is using opacity

```
<div>
  <button class="text-white opacity-0 hover:opacity-100">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that's true, i should correct what I needed though. I tried opacity but it wasn't aesthetically pleasing so i went with the another option of setting a private boolean and using v-if on the target element.

Comment: It's fair to consider that `opacity-0` elements keep taking up screen space while not in absolute positioning