# Navbar in React and Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, dropdown, navbar

I have a task to create a navbar with two dropdowns on hover using Tailwind css. I have read the Tailwind documentation regarding hover, focus etc. I have tried using groups and group modifiers but couldn't get it to work.

So I decided to ask you guys for some directions and help if possible. How would you approach this?

Below is the code I am currently working with:

`

```
    {/*First button - Resources */}
    <div className='flex item-center flex-col justify-center m-5 relative group'>
        <button className='p-3 text-sm hover:bg-slate-400'>Resources</button>

      <div className='group-hover: block'>
        <ul className='mt-2 flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
            <li><a href='#'>New Starter</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Stakeholders</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Checklists</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
        
    </div>

    {/*Second button - Tools */}

    <div className='flex item-center flex-col justify-center relative group'>
        <button className='p-3 text-sm hover:bg-slate-400'>Tools</button>

      <div className='group-hover: block'>
        <ul className='mt-2 flex flex-col items-center'>
            <li><a href='#'>TIE</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Asset manager</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>PM</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
        
    </div>


</div>`
```

Comment: I think you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917112/displaying-button-when-hovering-over-div-in-tailwindcss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'd want no space between `group-hover:` and `block` – you'd want `group-hover:block`.
- The element that you're applying `group-hover:block` to already has `display: block` by default so this has no effect. Typical dropdown elements are not visible in their default state, so consider applying `display: none` via the `hidden` class.

Putting it all together:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class='flex item-center flex-col justify-center m-5 relative group'>
  <button class='p-3 text-sm hover:bg-slate-400'>Resources</button>

  <div class='hidden group-hover:block'>
    <ul class='mt-2 flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
      <li><a href='#'>New Starter</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Stakeholders</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Checklists</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>

<div class='flex item-center flex-col justify-center relative group'>
  <button class='p-3 text-sm hover:bg-slate-400'>Tools</button>

  <div class='hidden group-hover:block'>
    <ul class='mt-2 flex flex-col items-center'>
      <li><a href='#'>TIE</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Asset manager</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>PM</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```